# Generate Dynamic Rows & Columns with itemtemplate using Webform Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, webforms

I want to make data entry grid with validations and item template field which consist of multiple Webform controls. like SAP and Ax Dynamics data entry grid. 
Kindly help me if you anyone have this kind of sample grid.

```
        //You can store a DataTable in the session state
        DataTable table = Session["Table1"] as DataTable;

        table = new DataTable();
        DataColumn colid = table.Columns.Add("sno", typeof(Int32));
        DataColumn l_ID = table.Columns.Add("l_ID", typeof(String));
        table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { colid };
        colid.ReadOnly = true;
        l_ID.ReadOnly = true;
        getlist();
        //List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = grid.GRCol();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn(list[i]["fieldid"], typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add(dcol);
        }

        #region rowgenrate
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            DataRow aRow = table.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (i == 1 && j > 1)
                {
                    string abc = table.Columns[j].ToString();
                    aRow["sno"] = i;
                    aRow["l_ID"] = "001";
                    aRow[abc] = "";
                    //table.Rows.Add(aRow);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (j > 1)
                    {
                        aRow["sno"] = i;
                        aRow["l_ID"] = "";
                        aRow[j] = "";
                    }`enter code here`
                    //table.Rows.Add(aRow);
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(aRow);
        }
        #endregion
        Session["Table1"] = table;
```

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Comment: cell value lost in generate new row